# How can i close tab or reopen popup tab in javascript?

Tags: javascript, window.open, window.closed

I am trying to get the reference of the newly opened tab and use it in the same function to close the tab and reopen,
for more details:
I want to create a Java script button

1. on the first click open a new tab
2. on the second click of the same button close the tab and reopen the same tab

```js
var Window; 
// Function that open the new Window 
function windowOpen() { 
  Window = window.open( "https://www.google.com/", "_blank", "width=400, height=450"); 

  // if (window.opener) {
  //     window.opener.announceWindow( window );
  // }
}
// function announceWindow( win ) {
//     window.close();
// }
```

```html
<button onclick="windowOpen()" target=_blank> 
    Open Window
</button>
```

Comment: *"I am trying to get the reference of the newly opened tab..."* ok, but what is the problem you are facing, what is your real question?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
let google;
let open = false;
function toggleWindow() {
    open = !open;
    if (open) {
        google = window.open("https://www.google.com/", "_blank", "width=400, height=450");
    } else {
        google.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```js
var Window = window.open('https://www.google.com');
function windowOpen() {
  if(Window !== null){
      alert("Window alreay open");
      Window.close();
      Window = null;
  }else {
    Window = window.open('https://www.google.com');
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="windowOpen()">
  Open Window
</button>
```

**[open()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)** function opens a new tab. It's **name** property has **_blank** value by default. But if you close the tab manually, then you have to refresh the page to work JS properly otherwise you will get alert **"Window already open"** even after the closing of the tab.